# Creating a .desktop file with AD in URL

Tags: .desktop, ldap

I create shortcut .desktop file.

to specify a local dir I use

```
 URL=file:///home/archemar/whatever
```

Now I want to connect to a network share, that would be

```
 URL=smb://localnas/path/to/dir
```

I am trying to specify a user in an active directory ldap domain name

I have tried

```
URL=smb://AD\\Archemar@localnas/path/to/dir
```

But local domain is still being asked, what do I need to specify ?

Comment: Why do you need to create desktop file when after permanent mounting it you can access it from launcher?

Comment: @daisy those are coporate shares, I cannot use permanent mount since this would imply hard coding my corporate password (which I change every month), I rather mount it manually on demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong format for SMB Domain URIs. The valid one is [available here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/smb).

In short, you want it to be in this format:

```
smb://[domain;]user[:password]@server/share
```

Or, in your specific case, your URI would look like:

```
smb://AD;Archemar@localnas/path/to/dir
```

Replace what you currently have with this and try to use your `.desktop` file. Note, as mentioned above, you can also include your password, but note that it will be stored in plaintext, which may be an unacceptable security risk.

Comment: this worked, I have no need te re-select AD domain.